# Шапка с сложным заголовком DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

Добрый день! Можно ли как-нибудь в Windows Forms или WPF реализовать в компоненте DataGrid вот такую вот шапку? Если нет, то каким образом выйти из ситуации?

Я пробовал делать экспорт такой таблицы из Excel, однако, получаются сбитые заголовки.

Всем заранее спасибо за ответы

[image: вот так вот нужно]

Comment: Если вам нужны сложные гриды со спанами и прочим, проще всего воспользоваться сторонними контролами, в которых это всё в готовом виде.

Comment: @Discord: Посоветуете конкретный контрол?

Comment: @VladD Любой. Любой платный набор констролов имеет датагрид, потому что датагрид — центр Вселенной для любого энтерпрайза. Если спаны — не единственное, что вам надо, то можете сравнить остальные фичи, синтаксис и прочее. У всех есть триал. В принципе можно попытаться найти что-нибудь опенсорсовое, особенно если у вас потребности ограничиваются спанами, но тут ничего посоветовать не могу. Ну и можно нагородить костыли для стандартного датагрида, см. google://wpf+datagrid+column+span, собственно. Я бы что-нибудь накопипастил, но тут за 30 градусов, мне лень шевелиться...

Comment: @Discord: Мне повезло никогда не сталкиваться с энтерпрайзом, поэтому я расчехлил Visual Studio и уже было собирался ваять костыль.

Comment: @Discord: А кстати, чем отличается `DataGrid` без `AutoGenerateColumns` от `ListView`?

Comment: @VladD Э... Тем, что у ListView могут быть разные представления, а грид — это только грид?

Comment: @Discord: То есть, ListView строго (или почти строго) богаче по возможностям?

Comment: @VladD Датагрид лучше приспособлен для редактирования данных.

Comment: @VladD: `LIstView` в WPF - эдакий "не пришей кобыле хвост". Его grid view убог тем, что не позволяет включить заполнение для колонок (поставить ширину типа `"25*"`). Прочие "view" для него из коробки осутствуют, что само по себе намекает на его полезность. А по сути, практически все, что позволяет воображение, можно реализовать связкой ItemsControl + нужный вариант ItemsPanel, и это будет более общая реализация, нежели наследник `ViewBase`. Ну и плюс он действительно больше "view", в то время как `DataGrid` больше заточен на редактирование (та же поддержка `IEditableObject`).

Comment: @Dennis: А это реально надо? Я просто всю жизнь использовал ListView (ну или какого-то предка), всё равно обычно нужен свой DataTemplate.

Comment: @VladD: Вы уточните, что именно это... а то в комментарии куча всего.

Comment: @Dennis: ну, заполнение для колонок.

Comment: @VladD: конечно, надо. Типовая ситуация для табличных данных - несколько колонок с цифрами/lookup'ами + наименование (заголовок и пр. текст). Обычно эта колонка самая широкая, и для нее удобно включить заполнение (юзеру удобно). Более того, иногда удобно задать заполнение для двух колонок, да еще и относительно (чтоб одна из них была заведомо шире другой). Делать это на `ListView` - ужасно.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать поковырять бесплатную библиотеку XCeed'a - Extended WPF Toolkit. У них там свой DataGrid и документация в наличии